# Error in Python IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data.csv'

Tags: python, errno

In Python, I have a script, I'm trying to use the python `open("data.csv")` command to open a CSV file that I have in the Python script directory.

There is a file there called `data.csv`.

The python script indicates an error:

```
Error in Python IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data.csv'
```

What does this error mean and how do I fix it?

Here is the minimal code in the script that reproduces the error:

```
open("data.csv")
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try to give the full path to your csv file

```
open('/users/gcameron/Desktop/map/data.csv')
```

The python process is looking for file in the directory it is running from.

Answer (score 9):

[open](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open) looks in the current working directory, which in your case is `~`, since you are calling your script from the `~` directory.

You can fix the problem by either

- `cd`ing to the directory containing `data.csv` before executing the script, or
- by using the full path to `data.csv` in your script, or
- by calling [os.chdir(...)](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.chdir) to change the current working directory from within your script. Note that all subsequent commands that use the current working directory (e.g. `open` and `os.listdir`) may be affected by this.

Comment: os.chdir() should be used with care or better yet not at all in this case (os.path.join could be used instead).

Answer (score 2):

You need to either provide the absolute path to data.csv, or run your script in the same directory as data.csv.

Answer (score 2):

It's looking for the file in the current directory.

First, go to that directory

```
cd /users/gcameron/Desktop/map
```

And then try to run it

```
python colorize_svg.py
```