# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory on Mac

Tags: python, excel, operating-system, xlrd

I've tried to open a file that does exist but I keep getting an error message of:

```
No such file or directory on Mac
```

I have made sure it is in the same directory as the python code. I've also tried changing the name of the excel doc and whether the doc is `.xls` and `.xlsx` but it has not worked.

Here are several versions I've tried, but so far they all give me the same result.

```
import os.path
book = open(os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/Crimes.xlsx"))
```

or

```
import xlrd
import os.path
book = xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join("/Users/caitlinwesterfield",'Crime.xls')
```

or

```
import xlrd
book = xlrd.open_workbook('Crime.xls')
```

or

```
import xlrd
book = open('/Users/caitlinwesterfield/Desktop/Crime.xls', "r")
```

or

```
import xlrd
book = open("~/Crime.xls", "r")
```

or

```
import xlrd
book = open(os.path.expanduser(r"~/Desktop/Crime.xls"))
```

or

```
import xlrd
book = open('Crime.xls')
```

or

```
import xlrd
book = open(os.path.expanduser("/Users/caitlinwesterfield/Desktop/Crime.xls"))
```

or

```
import xlrd
import os
book = xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join("/Users/caitlinwesterfield","TypesOfCrime.xls"))
```

or

```
import xlrd
book = xlrd.open_workbook("typesofcrime.xls")
```

Comment: Did you try open a text file instead of `.xls` file?

Comment: It still could not find the document as a .txt file, but I'm not sure how this would allow me to iterate through rows later in the excel doc

Comment: So as you said, it could not find **any** file. Can you write some text into a file?

Comment: The issue is that the code could find the file and find the path, it just could not find the document in xlrd.open_workbook or open . I'm not sure what that means

Comment: For example, this code works: print os.path.abspath('Types_Of_Crime.xlsx')

Comment: Well, so Python could find the file, but when you're trying to open it it raise  `No such file or directory`? That's impossible!

Comment: Yes but that is what's happening!

Comment: When I used this: book = xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join(os.path.abspath('Types_Of_Crime.xlsx'))
 The result is [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/caitlinwesterfield/Types_Of_Crime.xlsx' 
meaning it found the path, but did not open the file

Comment: Wait, I'm trying to open a doesn't exist file, it raise `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such...`, but you got an `IOError`?

Comment: Yes I got an IOError

Comment: I found [another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000455/error-in-python-ioerror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory-data-csv) question, but seems like you've tried all of the solutions...What's that file looks like?

Comment: I tried the code on multiple different documents and it seems that I cannot open any files to read using code of : book = open(os.path.abspath('text.docx')         What do you suggest? I am using canopy and have imported the os package (which is working as the error is unable to find '/Users/caitlinwesterfield/text.docx'
)

Comment: Well, which version of Python are you using? I think this problem is about Python...

Comment: Are you on an HFS+ OS/X Volume that is case sensitive? If you are, have you verified that the full path and file name matches the proper case?

Comment: I think so Michael? I directly copied and pasted both the full path and file name. And Kevin I think Python 2.1? I think it says I am in IPython , but I'm not sure what this means

Comment: You said that "The issue is that the code could find the file and find the path" but I'm not sure that's the case. The mere fact that you can do os.path.abspath on the path doesn't show that the path is visible to python: abspath just manipulates paths as strings and doesn't care whether the file/path in question really exists (try it with a missing file!). What happens if you do os.path.realpath instead?

Comment: Using realpath still said it No such file or directory

Comment: OK. So that makes me think that it really can't find the file or the path. Can you try os.listdir("/Users/caitlinwesterfield"). If that fails, can you try os.listdir("/Users") and if that fails what about os.listdir("/") ?

Comment: PS if you reply to someone else's comment, it's a good idea to start your answer with that user's handle (e.g. @CaitlinM or @circular-ruin). That way the user will be notified about the reply...

Comment: Ok @circular-ruin after trying os.listdir("/Users/caitlinwesterfield") the error I got was      
----> 8 book = open(c)

TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found

Comment: The same occurred for os.listdir("/")

Comment: Also I'm a bit confused on how opening to these areas would allow me to find my document? I'm sorry I'm such a nuisance. I'm (clearly) very new to python

Comment: Sorry, I am confused by your last answer. Are you saying that when you tried typing  os.listdir("/") at the python prompt, python responded with an exception "TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found"?

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you open those areas directly... in fact if you did open(os.listdir("/")) that wouldn't work at all! (And indeed that would explain the error you reported just above.) The idea is that if you try `print(os.listdir("/") )` it will either print the contents of /, or will give an error message. If it works, then you can try `print(os.listdir("/Users") )` and so on. You kind of work up to  `Users/caitlinwesterfield/Desktop/Crime.xls` and see at what point the problem hits....

Comment: @circular-ruin thank you that made a lot more sense. I worked my way all the way up to Desktop, but once I added Crime.xlsx I received this error: OSError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/Users/caitlinwesterfield/Desktop/Crime.xlsx' 
Does this mean it cannot find Crime at all? When I put Crime in quotations it did not work either

Comment: @CaitlinM : Is it Crime or Crimes ? You have used both in your question. Maybe you just have the name wrong? And is it Crimes.xlsx or Crime.xlsx. I think you need to verify **exactly** what the file name is.

Comment: OK. You wouldn't expect to be able to `os.listdir` a file like `Users/caitlinwesterfield/Desktop/Crime.xls`, so the error you got in the end is not surprising. So just to be clear, `print(os.listdir('/Users/caitlinwesterfield/Desktop/'))` gives some output (no error message), but `print(open('/Users/caitlinwesterfield/Desktop/Crime.xlsx').readlines())` gives `No such file or directory`?

Comment: Wait that worked!!!! Thank you!!!!

Comment: @CaitlinM : what was the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure. But when I copied and pasted in open('/Users/caitlinwesterfield/Desktop/Crime.xlsx') it worked

Comment: @CaitlynM: You are aware that if you go through your question, you actually never tried loading that particular file name. You either left off the trailing `x` in xlsx, you spelled Crime with an `s` in some of them and in others you didn't use the directory `Desktop`. My opinion is that you have been using the wrong file and/or path name all along.

Comment: Now that we know the exact file name you were trying to use, my guess is that this works `book = open(os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/Crime.xlsx"))` This is the same as your very first attempt in your question except I have removed the `s` from Crime. Does that work?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking if there was a permissions issue?

Open up your terminal and cd to the right directory

```
cd -l
```

Here is what those permissions mean:

```
rwxrwxrwx  <-- r refers to read, w to write, and x to execute
---------  <-- a hyphen refers to the permission not existing
```

[image]

Try running:

```
chmod 777 Crimes.xlsx
# you might need to add sudo if you get permission error:
sudo chmod 777 Crimes.xlsx
```

[image source and more info](http://www.techradar.com/how-to/computing/apple/terminal-101-file-permissions-1305647)

[how to use the terminal](http://www.macworld.co.uk/feature/mac-software/get-more-out-of-os-x-terminal-3608274/)

Comment: If the error really is about permissions, I think the error would be `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: filename`.

Comment: Yeah I don't think it is a permission issue

Comment: Right, didn't catch that

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the file is NOT corrupt, e.g. total file size is correct.

Download the file again if it is from online.

This set of ACTIONS solved this problem in my case:

```
(Error 2 - No such file or directory.)
```

I hope this helps you too.