# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'userDetails'

Tags: python

My program needs to read an external Notepad (.txt) file which has usernames and passwords. (Both the program and the document are on my desktop.) I used this code to read it.

```
file = open ("userDetails.txt", "r")

userDetails = file.readlines()

file.close()
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'userDetails'
```

I tried putting them in a folder together, but still got the same error.  Any ideas?

Comment: Does the error report the filename as  `userDetails`, as you say, or `userDetails.txt`, as your code indicates?  Check that notepad has not added another `.txt` to the end of the filename, which it has a habit of doing.  I suggest you use a more powerful and robust editor for text files, like Notepad++ for example.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Please have a look at [Python Language](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/topics) too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000455/error-in-python-ioerror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory-data-csv possible duplicate hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try and specify the full file path to the text file when you open it:

i.e `/full/path/to/file.txt` such as `/Users/Harrison/Desktop/file.txt`

Right now it's likely that Python is looking for the file in the default Python working directory.

Also, it's a better practice when working with files to open it like this:

```
with open('/path/to/userDetails.txt') as file:
    file_contents = file.readlines()
    # or whatever else you'd like to do
```

... and [here](http://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/maintainability/not_using_with_to_open_files.html) is an explanation as to why it's good to do it this way.

If you're having trouble locating the full file path, here's how you can do it for [Mac](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-copy-a-file-path-in-os-x/) and [Windows](http://www.pcworld.com/article/251406/windows_tips_copy_a_file_path_show_or_hide_extensions.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think your userDetails.txt does not reside in the python script working directory. So you have to specify your file names for input and output like e.g.:

```
# ----------------------------------------
# open file and select coordinates
# ----------------------------------------
pathnameIn = "D:/local/python/data"
filenameIn = "910-details.txt"
pathIn = pathnameIn + "/" + filenameIn

pathnameOut = "D:/local/python/data"
filenameOut = "910-details-reduced.txt"
pathOut = pathnameOut + "/" + filenameOut

fileIn = open(pathIn,'r')
fileOut = open(pathOut,'w')
```